# I want to detect new line from the text view.

Tags: android

How can I detect new line character from the text view in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely but you could always get the contents of the TextView using it's getText() method then use the String methods such as `contains("\n")` or `replace("\n", "<new stuff>")` to check for new lines and process it. Then you can just set the text in the TextView to the new string using setText().

Comment: Thanx frd...my question again is my strin like this